# How to replace deprecated android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-support-library

Yesterday (17-10-2014) I have update Android SDK and `support-library-v4.jar` of my App, now I get deprecation warning related to `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, reading [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) seems that I have to use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in `support-library-v7.appcompact.jar`.

Here some parts of my Activity that could be relevants:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ActionBar bar;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_infoviewer);

        bar = this.getActionBar();

        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
        initNavMenu();
        try {
            mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    ....

    private void initNavMenu() {
        NavMenuAdapter mAdapter = MyDrawers.getDefaultDrawer(MyActivity.this, true);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GreenMoneyDark));
        if (mDrawerList != null) mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener(MyActivity.this, mDrawer, mDrawerList));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                                           DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.action_drawer,
                    R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            bar.setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            bar.setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to copy support-library-v7 and replace

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

with

```
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

this has caused compilation problem in

```
 public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                                               DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
                super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.action_drawer,
                        R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
            }
```

So I have tried to replace `R.drawable.action_drawer` with

```
public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                                           DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout,new Toolbar(MyActivity.this) ,
                    R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }
```

this compiles but crash at Runtime with

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr;
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:190)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:186)
```

Note that `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` is correctly added in project dependencies
[image]

Comment: Change your import from v4 to v7 and it worked

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Adding only `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` to library dependencies is not enough, you have also to import in your project the module that you can find in your SDK at the path `\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`and after that add module dependencies configuring the project structure in this way

[image]

otherwise are included only the class files of support library and the app is not able to load the other resources causing the error.

In addition as reVerse suggested replace this

```
public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                                           DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout,new Toolbar(MyActivity.this) ,
                    R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }
```

with

```
public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                                           DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you works! However the drawer toggle button becomes dark, how can change the color?

Comment: update Drawer is not shown on Jelly Bean and previous versions

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442135/replace-deprecated-android-support-v4-app-actionbardrawertoggle-with-support-v7

Answer (score 60):

There's no need for you to use super-call of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` which requires the [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html). This means instead of using the following constructor:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

You should use this one:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

So basically the only thing you have to do is to remove your custom `drawable`:

```
super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
```

More about the "new" ActionBarDrawerToggle [in the Docs (click)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

Comment: I have tried to follow your suggestion but crashes with this issue:`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
            at android.support.v7.app.DrawerArrowDrawable.<init>(DrawerArrowDrawable.java:64)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:469)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:222)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:150)`

Comment: You're using Eclipse right? Did you check the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in your project properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export? Furthermore it may be helpful to move the v7-appcompat to the top.

Comment: I use IntelliJ I have added the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` to the project dependencies in the same way of support-v4 (otherwise doesn-t even compile)

Comment: Mhkay unfortunately I'm not familiar with IntelliJ. In Android Studio you just need to add `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"` to your `build.gradle` file and you're good to go.

Comment: I have checked many times if the library dependency is correctly configured, there is some other reason that cause the issue, I have thought that the library maybe is corrupted but I have tried to download and add it again from SDK manager with no result

Comment: following the other answer I correctly configured the library but Drawer is not shown on Jelly Bean and previous versions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442135/replace-deprecated-android-support-v4-app-actionbardrawertoggle-with-support-v7

Comment: In my case it does not crash, but toggle button doesn't appear at all anymore.

Comment: Works for me, but don't forget to add import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

Answer (score 27):

you must use `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;`

and use the constructor

```
public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout)
{
    super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
}
```

and if the drawer toggle button becomes dark then you must use the supportActionBar provided in the support library.

You can implement supportActionbar from this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

Comment: Thanks, a manual import of `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;` worked for me. Even though I have auto-imports usually, that one did not auto-import.

Comment: And delete `import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;`

Answer (score 8):

Insted of

```
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

You can use

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```