# Replace deprecated android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle with support.v7 version cause drawer not works on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-support-library

Following the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439619/how-to-replace-deprecated-android-support-v4-app-actionbardrawertoggle/26440823#26440823) i have replaced `ActionBarDrawerToggle`  of support v4 library that in latest update(rev 21) has been deprecated with the latest `ActionBarDrawerToggle` of `support-v7 library`.

Now the drawer works on Android Lollipop Emulator without deprecation warnings but when I test the app on a Jelly Bean real device no drawer and no toggle drawer button is shown.

What the hell appened with this support library update? How could I fix this issue without downgrade to previous version?

Here my layout

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!--  content view -->

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/drawer_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- nav drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#F3F3F4"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your layout? new ActionBarDrawerToggle works fine for me

Comment: see the update to the question

Comment: please try to subclass from ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity.

Comment: I have tried to replace all `FragmentActivity` with `ActionBarActivity` but app crashes with this error `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` could you give me more details?

Comment: yep, please take a look here http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/ and here https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: I have also tried to add AppCompact Theme as parent theme but `mybar = this.getActionBar();` get a null value and activity crashes

Comment: @nikis I have tried the sample in your link but navigation drawer button dowsn't appears. also in api21 I'm not able to enable drawer button

Comment: you should use get/setSupportActionBar instead if you are using ActionBarActivity, works fine for me with NavigationDrawer. If it doesn't work, please post updated code of your activity

Comment: I have follwed all suggestions, now the ActionBar and drawer appear but all styles are ignored and I cannot change the action bar colors, also the commands to enable images or define the number of icons to show seem ignored, all icon buttons go in overflow menu

Comment: setting action bar color works fine for me, I'm not sure what might be the source of issue

Comment: you use the stile.xml file to set the color?

Comment: yes, with parent theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: If you use ActionBarActivity are you also forced to have to use the support version of Fragment since ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity?

Comment: I use the support version of Fragment (I don't know if there is a better alternative) extend ActionBar use AppCompat, added a style.xml that extends AppCompat but all my color setting are ignored and all the menu items are shown in overflow menu also if some menu items are set as always visible :(

Answer (score 6):

1. To get `ActionBarDrawerToggle` v7 to work properly you need to extends your Activity class from `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`
2. `ActionBarActivity` v7 must be used with `Theme.AppCompat` theme from the `appcompat-v7:21` support library.
3. Unless you want to switch from `ActionBar` to `ToolBar`, **don't** add `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` when extending `Theme.AppCompat`. Doing so will make your `ActionBarActivity` have no default `ActionBar` decor, and `getSupportActionBar` will return null. You'll need to provide your own `ToolBar` and call `setSupportActionBar` first to make `getSupportActionBar` work.

Comment: See the comment on my question, I get other issues also in this way