# Slide Menu without ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock, slide, android-support-library

I have seen much exemples to implement the slide menu using Sherlock, but all using too the ActionBarDrawerToggle that is deprecated.
Anyone have a exemple for slide menu with sherlock without the use of ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: Instead of sherlock, you can use support library. It will get rid of this deprecated component also. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26439619/1288725)

Comment: you want to get rid of deprecated `ActionBarDrawerToggle` imported from `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` , have you included `support-library-v7.appcompact.jar` in your build path?