# How to use deprecated ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android

```js
this.navDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,this.getApplicationContext(), this.navDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name ){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(navDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(appTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
```

I'm new to android i i'm making an app in which i was using Navigation Drawer i was following a tutorial but then in the end i stuck on `ActionBarDrawerToggle()` which i think is now deprecated and that tutorial was made earlier please can anyone tell me how to use deprecated  `ActionBarDrawerToggle` or any other way to use  **`android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;`** ??
please explain in detail as i'm new to android and programming.
[image]
i also imported 
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

As the [official oracle Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html) hints,

> You may have heard the term, "self-deprecating humor," or humor that
>   minimizes the speaker's importance.
>   A deprecated class or method is like that. It is no longer important.
>   It is so unimportant, in fact, that you should no longer use it, since
>   it has been superseded and may cease to exist in the future.

And also stated in the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)

> This class is deprecated. Please use ActionBarDrawerToggle in
>   support-v7-appcompat.

That being said, you should try to find a different solution to your problem. For example, you could use the support v7 version as suggested by the Android docs. [Here is an example on what you could do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439619/how-to-replace-deprecated-android-support-v4-app-actionbardrawertoggle)  instead of using a deprecated class.

Comment: but the problem is that i don't know how to implement android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: I've provided a link for you to use as reference. @Jazz

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the support v4 ActionBarDrawerToggle. Deprecated libraries will crash your app unexpectedly. I know this by experience. Use the support v7 one. [Here](https://github.com/danigonlinea/NavDra-material/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/danigonlinea/navdramaterial/activities/Main.java) is a pretty simple implementation.