# Actionbar v7 Toggle no space to title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toggle, space

My app was using android v4 toggle so far.

Now I switched to v7 appcompat toggle. Therefore I followed these steps: [How to replace deprecated android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439619/how-to-replace-deprecated-android-support-v4-app-actionbardrawertoggle).

This worked for me. The problem now is that there is absolutely no space between the toggle icon and the left screen border and the title. How can I add some space there so that it looks like the Google play store?

I've got an application icon on every activity. I tried removing it by using @android:color/transparent. This removed the icon but then there is still no space, the actionbar title just aligns straight to the v7 toggle icon.

Looks like this http://pl.vc/4jdg3
should look like this http://pl.vc/1oqh6

Comment: please show an image of what you mean by you have no space

Comment: Looks like this http://pl.vc/4jdg3 should look like this http://pl.vc/1oqh6

Comment: do you have any ideas?